# How to get parent id from child id?

Tags: php, arrays

my Database structure looks like

```
id|parent_id|category_name|
1 |   0     |Vehicle
2 |   0     |Tv
3 |   0     |Phone
4 |   1     |Bmw X Series
5 |   2     |Led Tv
6 |   2     |Plazma Tv
7 |   3     |Samsung
8 |   3     |Iphone
9 |   4     |Bmw X7
```

how can we find the top category if we assume that we know the subcategory.
for example:
when parent_id = 2

how can i create below outputs or derivatives

Tv > Led Tv

when parent_id = 4

Vehicle > Bmw X Series > Bmw X7

My code:

```
function get_key($arr, $id)
        {
            foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
                if ($val['id'] === $id) {
                    return $key;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function get_parent($arr, $id)
        {
            $key = get_key($arr, $id);
            if ($arr[$key]['parent_id'] == 0)
            {
                return $id;
            }
            else
            {
                return get_parent($arr, $arr[$key]['parent_id']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the variable $arr ? in your code

Comment: you can think of it as categories coming from the database. $arr = $categories

Comment: Why you start with 4 which is `Bmw X Series` to get `Bmw X7` - it seems more clear to start with 9 ? If you have some bmw in the table, the result will be undefined

Comment: I think the parent_id is logical to start.

Comment: Ok. Add `10 |   4     | Bmw X5`. What will be a result of get_parent($arr, 4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion at all. The first function - get_key - is fine. But the second one you need to change. And you should change logic with id to start with. If you have some sub-categories under start id, the result will be undefined. You can make path from root only to category, you set

```
function breadcrumbs($arr, $id) {
  $ret = [];
  // untill top category or incorrect data
  while ($id and ! is_null($key = get_key($arr, $id))) {
    // save current category name
    array_unshift($ret, $arr[$key]['category_name']);
    // step up
    $id = $arr[$key]['parent_id'];
  }
  return implode(' > ', $ret);
}

echo breadcrumbs($arr, 9); // Vehicle > Bmw X Series > Bmw X7
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/933997)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. is working. thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recurcive function:

```
function getById($array, $id){
  foreach ($array as $a) {
     if ($a['id'] == $id) {
        return $a;
     }
   }
 return null;
}

function findP($arr, $id) {
    $search = getById($arr, $id);
    $parentId = $search['parent_id'];
    if ($parentId == 0) {
        return $search['id'];
    }
    return findP($arr, $parentId);
}
```

Comment: I checked and it's not working. you can find the solution above.